# Transferring sorting loop results to another array

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, loops

Here's a loop to sort an array from min to max, I need the result of this loop to be put into another array so I can filter and remove the numbers that occur only once and find the last member of what's left.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define buffas 1024
void main() {
    int arr[buffas],i,j,element,no,temp;

    printf("\nEnter the no of Elements: ");
    scanf("%d", &no);
    for(i=0; i<no; i++) {
        printf("\n Enter Element %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
    for(i=0; i<no; i++) {
        for(j=i; j<no; j++) {
            if(arr[i] > arr[j]) {
                temp=arr[i];
                arr[i]=arr[j];
                arr[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nSorted array:");

    for(i=0; i<no; i++) {
        printf("\t%d",arr[i]);
    }

    getch();
}
```

How do I change the

```
printf("\t%d",arr[i]);
```

To fill another array and then sort that to remove single entries and leave ony those that repeat at least once.
eg. the first aray is

> 2 2 1 6 9 9

and after the second sorting the result should be

> 2 2 9 9

Comment: Could you please edit your post and indent and comment your code?

Comment: seems assignment question, did you try to implement second sorting?

Comment: Sorry for the indentation, I can't seem to get it right.
I didn't try second sorting, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: By looping through each element of the ordered array, you can check if the next or previous element is the same as the current (taking into account the bounds) and if so, add it to the second array.

Comment: Step through the sorted array, finding ranges of rows with the same value, and copying those rows to the target array.  You only need to count the number of repeats for each row value.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define buffas 16

int main(void)
{
  /* Instead of original input and sorting code */
  int arr[] = { 1, 2, 2, 6, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 };
  int no = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

  /* Code to copy only duplicated elements in arr */
  int copy[buffas];
  int n = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < no; i++)
  {
    int j;
    for (j = i + 1; j < no; j++)
    {
      if (arr[i] != arr[j])
        break;
    }
    if (j - i > 1)
    {
      for (int k = i; k < j; k++)
        copy[n++] = arr[k];
      i = j - 1;
    }
  }

  /* Print results for verification */
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("c[%d] = %d\n", i, copy[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

The code has been run with various lengths of sorted array and different data in the array; it seems to be correct.  The code above produces the output:

```
c[0] = 2
c[1] = 2
c[2] = 9
c[3] = 9
c[4] = 10
c[5] = 10
c[6] = 10
```

Note that the code uses the C99 feature of declaring variables in a `for` loop control statement; if you're on Windows and without C99 support, you'll need to declare `i` and `k` outside the loops.  If you're using GCC, you need to add `-std=c99` or a similar option.

Comment: Thank you this is incredibly helpful!